# Are multiline lists valid in Terraform?

Tags: terraform

I currently have the following.

```
module "module-name" {
  source                              = "./directory"
  environment                         = var.environment
  team_names                          = ["team-a", "team-b", "team-c", "team-d"]
```

This clearly makes the `team_names` line very long. Is it valid to change to this?

```
module "module-name" {
  source                              = "./directory"
  environment                         = var.environment
  team_names                          = [
                                          "team-a",
                                          "team-b",
                                          "team-c",
                                          "team-d"
                                        ]
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes. According to [Types and Values: Lists/Tuples](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/types.html#lists-tuples)

> List literals can be split into multiple lines for readability, but always require a comma between values. A comma after the final value is allowed, but not required. Values in a list can be arbitrary expressions.

Source:

- Terraform by HashiCorp. (n.d.). Types and Values - Configuration Language. [online] Available at: https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/types.html#lists-tuples [Accessed 28 Sep. 2021].

‌

Comment: Found the answer while writing the question so did not want it to go to waste :)

Comment: If you work with AWS/IAM + Terraform, you will see modules that have 1 IAM roles with 1 to many policies attached to it and it usually goes as a manual arn list or a data source holding that arn. Thats what I have seen in my work experience as big/long lists. So good job for finding this and its a valid answer!

Comment: These docs are written to describe specific situations in specific terms, but it might interest you to know a more general rule: when parsing expressions (the right-hand side of an `=` for an attribute inside a block) Terraform treats newlines as irrelevant whitespace inside both parentheses and square brackets, unless you undo that effect inside by opening braces (where the newline-sensitive processing comes back into effect again, so you can use newline-separated attribute syntax to define the object attributes).